# background image displays in firefox but not chrome

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, firefox, background

On my website my background image displays fine on firefox but on chrome there are large white boxes on the sides and those go away as the jquery image slide moves to the next image.I have the background image linked in the CSS to the body which all my content is in including the image slider.

**HERE IS THE LIVE WEBSITE**

http://wilsontsa.org/Technology%20courses/Technology%20Courses.html

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div id="bar">
</div>
<center>
<div id="pagecontainer">
<div id="container">
<div id="navigation">

<ul id="navigation">
<li id="techlink" class="dropdown"><a href="../Technology courses/Technology                 Courses.html" style="color:#046f83">Technology Courses</a>
<ul class="sub_navigation">
<li><a href="../Technology courses/Computer Science.html">&nbsp;Computer &nbsp;Science</a></li>
<li><a href="../Technology courses/Digital Video.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Digital Video&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="../Technology Courses/Technology Innovation.html">Technology Innovation</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Technology courses/Visual Design and Image Applications.html">Visual Design and Image App.</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Technology courses/Web Design.html">Web Design</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="englink" class="dropdown"><a href="../Engineering Courses/Engineering Courses.html">Engineering Courses</a>
<ul class="sub_navigation">
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Introduction to Engineering and Design.html">Intro to Engineering</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Computer Integrated Manufacturing.html">Computer Integrated Manufact.</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Principles of Engineering.html">Principles of Engineering</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Digital Electronics.html">Digital Electronics</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Civil Engineering and Architecture.html">Civil Engineering</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Aerospace Engineering.html">Aerospace Engineering</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Engineering Design and Development.html">Engineering Design</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/I-Stem.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I-STEM&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="STEMlink"><a href="../STEM/stem.html">STEM</a></li>
<li id="weblink" class="dropdown"><a href="../Webmaster/Evolution.html">Webmaster</a>
<ul class="sub_navigation">
<li><a href="../Webmaster/Evolution.html">Evolution</a></li>
<li><a href="../Webmaster/Adapting.html">Adapting</a></li>
<li><a href="../Webmaster/Advertising.html">Business Model</a></li>
<li><a href="../Webmaster/Solution.html">Future</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<div id="tsa" class="TSA">
  <li><a href="../TSA Chapter/TSA.html"><img  src="../Images/Design Images/TSA-LOGO.png" width="50" height="34" /></a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
</div> <!--navigation div --> 

</ul>
</center>

<div id="spacer">

<div id="wrapper">
<div>
<div class="slider-button" onclick="ss.move(-1)">&laquo;</div>
<div id="slideshow">
  <ul id="slides">
    <li><img src="../Javascript Photos/Picture1.png" width="900" height="300" alt="Coral Reef"></li>
    <li><img src="../Javascript Photos/Picture2.png" width="900" height="300" alt="Sea turtle">
    </li>
    <li><img src="../Javascript Photos/Picture3.png" width="900" height="450" alt="Coral Reef"></li>
    <li><img src="../Javascript Photos/Picture4.png" width="900" height="300" alt="Blue Fish"></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-button" onclick="ss.move(1)">&raquo;</div>
  </div>
  <ol id="pagination" class="pagination">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  </ol>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-image: url(Images/Tech nology%20Images/bg_Tech.gif);}
```

**Slider CSS**

```
li.current {
background:#102c75;}


#slideshow {
float:left; 
width:900px; 
height:300px; 
border:2px solid #ccc; 
background:#fff;
position:relative;
top:16px;
z-index:-1;}



#slides {
position:relative; 
width:900px; 
height:300px; 
list-style:none; 
overflow:auto;
z-index:-1;}



#slides li {
width:900px; 
height:300px;}



.fader-slide {
opacity:0; 
position:absolute;}

.fader-fade {
opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:opacity .4s; 
 -moz-transition:opacity .4s; 
 transition:opacity .4s;}



#content {
width:900px; 
height:270px; 
padding:15px 18px 15px 18px; 
background:#fff;}



#content h1 {
font:22px Georgia,Verdana; 
margin-bottom:15px; 
color:#036;}

#caption {
background:#fff; 
position:relative;}

#caption div {
position:absolute; 
bottom:0; 
left:0; 
width:900px; 
padding:15px 18px 10px 18px; 
background:#000; 
background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);}



#caption h2 {
font:18px Georgia,Verdana; 
margin-bottom:6px; 
color:#eee;}

#caption p {
line-height:1.4; 
color:#aaa;}
```

Comment: Please post some code or at the very least a link to your site.

Comment: Show us some code. It will be nice if you'll post it on [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)

Comment: do you want HMTL code or the CSS?

Comment: Can you provide an example? It's hard to find a reason for this behavior. Maybe there are other HTML elements, which overlays the background image. Did you examine the DOM structure with the built-in development tools of Google Chrome?

Comment: there is some of my code and the live website